# binding data when edit index is changed

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a gridview and I'm updating the data using the edit button.

when the update is completed I'm putting the grid back to the edit mode but i need to bind the data after the update so the problem is that when i use this command in the updating event:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = -1
```

the grid is not in the updating mode anymore nor in the editing mode so what is the event that i should use to bind the data using this command:

```
GridView1.DataBind()
```

and if i put the databind before changing the index, the editIndex will not change..

any help is much appreciated !

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating just reload griview again. you will get updated data and it will be editable again. for example

```
Private Sub LoadGridView1()
    //prepare data table from database
    GridView1.DataSource = //data table
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

 Protected Sub btnEditText_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        //perform your updation into data base
       LoadGridView1()

    End Sub
```

Comment: i'm reloading the gridview the problem is that once the updating event finishes i need to bind the data and return to the edit and when it returns to the edit the problem is the edit button is not clicked !! there is no event running at this step...

Comment: are you using RowUpdated method for EditIndex? it would be good if you post your code in your original post what exactly you are doing